# Send IP multicast over specific network interface

Tags: delphi, winsock, multicast

Currently I am sending multicast messages with a following code:

```
var
  addr: sockaddr_in;

FillChar(addr, SizeOf(addr), 0);
addr.sin_family := AF_INET;
addr.sin_addr.s_addr := inet_addr(PAnsiChar(_multicastGroup));
addr.sin_port := htons(_port);

//.................

if (sendto(fd, pmsg, Length(m), 0, addr, SizeOf(addr)) < 0) then begin
  perror('sendto');
end;
```

I did not invent this code, but taken from a C++ example found in Internet.

How to send IP Multicast over specific network interface?

Comment: This looks like Pascal, not C++.

Comment: Yes, it is Pascal. Why should it be C++?

Comment: You said you took it from a C++ example.

Comment: What are you binding to in the bind call?

Comment: @Dave Nottage: Nothing at all. I commented it out. If I bind one of LAN IP addresses (the PC has 3 network interfaces), receiving computer gets no data. If I receive, binding works. If I take receiving code, bind and join multicast group, but do sending, it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you binding to the address using port 0? I have some code working that uses Indy, however underneath the process is essentially the same